# XSLT output is giving empty results using xsltproc on CentOS7

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Can someone please explain to me why I get empty results when I run the command xsltproc test.xslt.

Here are the contents of test.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        <xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:text>Hello, World!</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</xml>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I would like to produce plain text answer that says "Hello World". The code that I used is above. XSLT standard is 1.0. No input xml.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the XSLT 1.0 needs an input XML. You can try `<root/>`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the stylesheet apart from that stray `</xml>` end tag. I wonder if that suggests that you tidied up the code for publication, and in doing so, removed the bug that was causing the problem?

Comment: It looks like @user210912 thinks that the XML declaration is a start-tag that requires a matching end-tag.

Answer (score 0):

> why I get empty results

You don't get "empty results". You get an error (which perhaps you don't see).

- You get an error because you have an extra `<` character before the
  namespace declaration;
- And you get an error because you have a `</xml>` end-tag at
  the end of the stylesheet.

If you fix your errors and do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Hello, World!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you should get the result you expect (provided you call the transformation with a well-formed XML input).

Answer (score 0):

This has worked by providing an input xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="text" />
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:text>Hello, World!</xsl:text>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>`enter code here`
```

Here is the input xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
      <node>Example node</node>
    </root>
```